# Terraform + VMWare - can't provision a server

Tags: vmware-vcenter, terraform

I'm trying to do some really basic stuff with Terraform on VMWare. I'm pretty sure I must be doing something obvious wrong as this is a really simple use case.

I have a test.tf file like this:

```
# Configure the VMware vSphere Provider
provider "vsphere" {
  user           = "${var.vsphere_user}"
  password       = "${var.vsphere_password}"
  vsphere_server = "${var.vsphere_server}"

  # if you have a self-signed cert
  allow_unverified_ssl = true
}

# Create a folder
resource "vsphere_folder" "test_folder" {
  path = "test_folder"
  datacenter = "Datacenter"
}


# Create a virtual machine within the folder
resource "vsphere_virtual_machine" "web" {
  datacenter = "Datacenter"
  name   = "terraform-web"
  folder = "${vsphere_folder.test_folder.path}"
  vcpu   = 2
  memory = 4096

  network_interface {
    label = "VM Network"
  }

  disk {
    datastore = "datastore1"
    template = "my-template/my-template.vmdk"
  }
}
```

I have a variable file with the user, password and VMware server in.

When I run terraform plan, it executes cleanly.

When I run terraform apply, I get:

```
* vsphere_virtual_machine.web: vm 'my-template/my-template.vmdk' not found
```

I've tried leaving off the my-template.vmdk off (so pointing at the template directory)
I've tried pointing it at the vmx file

What should I be putting for the disk location? Does anyone have a working example please?

Answer (score 0):

From github:

> **template** - (Optional) VM template name. If you want to deploy new VM from VM template, it's required. This argument is valid at the first disk. If not specified, empty disk will be created. For example, it's used for booting with iPXE.

Did you try just using the template name (drop the `.vmdk`?

Comment: Yep. Tried that too Didn't work.

Comment: Yep definitely a template. I took an OVA for a vanilla Ubuntu image I had, deployed it and then had vCenter create a template based off it. I have definitely confirmed that's the path in the datastore too.

I may be missing something obvious as I'm not really a VMWare or Terraform specialist, but the documentation for Terraform + VMWare is pretty rubbish - it doesn't even, for example, mention that you need vCenter and to specify a datacenter.

Don't suppose you have a working example I can take a look at Ulfy?

Comment: Can you link/upload the Terraform debug logs & `crash.log`? I no longer use Terraform in production; I currently deploy VMs using a PS/PowerCLI script I wrote. I'll poke around and see if I kept any scripts from it. Nothing jumps out as being syntactically wrong with your example though; however, I don't know what your VMware side looks like. The aforementioned logs might help give some insight.

Comment: I'll have to set up a new instance of VMware as the actual logs will likely contain loads of customer specific info which I can't share. I'll get on that shortly. 

In the mean time, why did you choose to move away from Terraform? I was also looking at potentailly looking to use PowerCLI, but the customer in question wants to have terraform to deploy across AWS/Azure/VMware etc, so I'll need a compelling reason to stop trying....

Comment: ...and the answer is..... *drum roll*.

The Terraform provider doesn't use VMWare templates, it needs to use existing VMware VMs. The VMs don't however, need to be up and running.

It's also worth noting that using vCenter 6.5 fixed a LOAD of problems I was having with 5.5.

Comment: @Tom, could you please put your comment as answer and mark it solved?